# how can I str_extract number using stringr in R

Tags: r

```
a <- c("AB，DF14:07GHJ456.9Y","RTY00:00KL23.40T")
```

How can I extract "456.9" and "23.40"?
And convert them to numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One base R way would be :

```
a <- c("AB，DF14:07GHJ456.9Y","RTY00:00KL23.40T")
b <- as.numeric(sub('.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+)[A-Z]', '\\1', a))
b
#[1] 456.9  23.4
```

Or using `stringr` :

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(a, '\\d+\\.\\d+(?=[A-Z]$)'))
#[1] 456.9  23.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stringr` with some regex:

```
library(stringr)
as.double(str_extract(a, pattern = "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(a, regexpr("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", a)))
#[1] 456.9  23.4
```